# How to pass variable in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want pass variable instead of number. I want to limit input based on my variable value.

```
if (isNaN(value) || value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,3}$/) === null
```

this is my expresssion, i want to pass variable "decimal". But i am not able to pass it.

```
const decimal=column.validations.decimalPlaces
```

I am trying to write like this `if (isNaN(value) || value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,decimal}$/) === null`
but its not working . how can i pass this decimal variable like this

Comment: not sure what about using template literal like this `if (isNaN(value) || value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,`${decimal}`}$/) === null`  ; NOTE it is like "if (isNaN(value) || value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,${backtick${decimal}backtick}$/)===null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would escape characters if regex is string:

```
value.match(`^\\d+\\.?\\d{0,${decimal}}$`) === null
```